# Let A be the set of numbers in the interval [0, 1] that have the digit “0” in the first, second or third place in their decimal expansion

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

MY QUETION:

Let A be the set of numbers in the interval [0, 1] that have the digit “0” in the first, second or third place in their decimal expansion.

Show that A belongs to the σ-algebra generated by the intervals.

Find m(A), where m denotes Lebesgue measure.

Anyone willing to give any help/advise/pointers on how to complete ?

Comment: Your construction of $A$ does not result in the $A$ defined in your first paragraph! Firstly, you appear to have replaced $0$ with $4$; and secondly, you are iterating the process an infinite number of times, not just three. Please clear this up.

Comment: OK, that's better! Your $A$ is actually the union of a _finite_ number of intervals; does this help?

Comment: @TonyK I'm not so much stuck on the concept but application and how I go about dealing with finding a lebesgue measure when the set of numbers in the interval [0, 1] that have the digit “0” in the first, second or third place in their decimal expansion.

Comment: I can't make any sense of that, I'm afraid. So try this: What is the Lebesgue measure of a finite union of disjoint intervals?

Comment: I'm unsure it's my first week of measure theory! I'm from an applied background so I'm trying to do extra questions so I can learn to understand these concepts. I'm just flummoxed my this question. @TonyK